# How to Deal With `self` Variable in JSON data swiftUI

Tags: json, swift, oauth, swiftui, decode

I am trying to access the [Schoology API](https://developers.schoology.com/api) from my app, designed for our school. I've been using the [OAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift) package for OAuth 1 support.

In the response from Schoology, this shows up multiple times

```
"links": {
    "self": "https:\/\/api.schoology.com\/v1\/messages\/inbox\/9999999"
}
```

Where I'm having difficulty is in decoding the JSON into a `Codable` Structure. I can't simply code for:

```
struct Links: Codable {
    let self:String
}
```

As `self` is already reserved by swift, it can't be used as a variable name. Is there another way to decode JSON data in Swift that would avoid this issue?

The full structure of the JSON response is printed below: (note: there are many messages in the array, all share the same structure.)

```
{
  "message": [
    {
      "id": 9999999,
      "subject": "Your homework is late, prepare for termination.",
      "recipient_ids": "9999999",
      "last_updated": 9999999,
      "mid": null,
      "author_id": 9999999,
      "message_status": "read",
      "message": null,
      "links": {
        "self": "https:\/\/api.schoology.com\/v1\/messages\/inbox\/9999999"
      }
    },
  ],
  "links": {
    "self": "https:\/\/api.schoology.com\/v1\/messages\/inbox?start=0&limit=20"
  },
  "unread_count": "0"
}
```

If you've gotten this far, I thank you. But if I haven't provided enough information, all the code's available on our [GitHub page](https://github.com/connorholm/ephsapp2020/tree/API) in the API branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a backtick to escape reserved words:

```
struct Links: Codable {
   var `self`: String
}
```

If you don't want to use `self`, you can map a json key to a different property using manually defined `CodingKeys`:

```
struct Links: Codable {
   var me: String

   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case me = "self"
   }
}
```

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)